# DMARC fail, but DKIM and SPF are passing

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, dkim, dmarc, amazon-ses

I am using AWS SES (in sandbox mode) to send an email to a GMail address.
Unfortunately it gets flagged as spam.

Google is nice enough to tell me in the message details that it is a DMARC failure

I read the official documentation : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-email-authentication-dmarc.html

Here is what confuses me (quotes from that page) :

- “In order to comply with DMARC, messages must be authenticated through either SPF or DKIM, or both.”
- “By complying with one of these authentication systems, your emails will comply with DMARC”

**My question is, why are both SPF and DKIM passing yet DMARC is failing?**

```
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@amazonses.com header.s=REDACTED header.b=REDACTED;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of REDACTED@eu-central-1.amazonses.com designates IP_REDACTED as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=REDACTED@eu-central-1.amazonses.com;
       dmarc=fail (p=QUARANTINE sp=QUARANTINE dis=QUARANTINE) header.from=example.com
```

The Return-Path ends in `amazonses.com`

(the DNS entries for SPF and DKIM on `example.com` are present).

Let me know if you need any additional information to get to the root of the issue

Answer (score 9, accepted):

DMARC does not test if SPF or DKIM has passed, but one of them must both pass and be *aligned* with the domain used in the `From:` header. Here, SPF passed with `eu-central-1.amazonses.com` and DKIM with `amazonses.com`. They are not *aligned* with i.e. do not match your `example.com`, so DMARC fails.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Now that the configuration is correct on the SES side there is a second dkim entry in the ARC-Authentication-Results headers with my domain, so it is aligned.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.

**I had set up the DKIM and SPF for the wrong AWS region.**

I am still confused that it passed.